# Ignore top directory when working on a subdirectory

Tags: git

I've got a remote repository like this :

```
Remote_project_name/
                Directory1/
                Directory2/
```

but locally, I'd like to work only on `Directory1/` as my git root directory.

I'm already working with [sparse-checkout](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/) so I can only checkout `Directory1/` but I can't find a way ignore the parent folder `Remote_project_name/`

Comment: Are you suggesting you have a `Remote_project_name` repo with two submodules? Git will look in current directory for `.git` before it goes up one level to check before it goes up one level to check… Your description of the situation doesn't make much sense unless your talking about submodules in which case this would not be an issue in the first place.

Comment: Try displaying the `.git` directories relative in that file list above. It might help others understand what you want in the end.